# Hibernate: cleaning up sessions

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, session, thread-safety

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class DAOFactory {
    @Inject private final SessionFactory factory;
    private final ThreadLocal<Session> session = new ThreadLocal<>();

    // In a nutshell: create an AbstractDAO associated with the session object held by the ThreadLocal above
    public <T> AbstractDAO<T> createObject(Class<T> objectClass) { ... }
}
```

The problem that I have is that these sessions need to be closed, and only the thread creating the DAO from `createObject()` can do that.  Clearly, `AbstractDAO` cannot have a close routine, since the same `Session` can be associated with multiple `AbstractDAO` objects, so `DAOFactory` has to shoulder the burden of closing sessions.  Still, there is a risk of dangling `Session`s: if the thread creating the `AbstractDAO` no longer exists, how can the associated `Session` be closed?

One approach I have is to have a cleanup method as follows:

```
public class DAOFactory {
    // createObject() uses Thread.getCurrentThread.getId() and sessionMap.computeIfAbsent()
    private final ConcurrentMap<Long, Session> sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void cleanup() {
        for (Session session : sessionMap.values()) {
            session.close();
        }
        sessionMap.clear();
    }
}
```

The question is "how safe is this approach", "is this a good idea", and "should this be done"?  If not, what's a good alternative?

Note that `DAOFactory` is largely created with some kind of testing situation in mind: one thread starts a test run and creates a `DAOFactory`, and it may spawn other threads that uses it.  The thread creating `DAOFactory` will always outlast any threads that it spawns, and will always be the one calling `cleanup()` at the end of a test.

Answer (score 0):

Manual Session management is not a good idea. Hibernate already offers a SPI, so that you don't have to do it yourself.

I suggest you start using Spring transaction management, which also offers automatic session management as well.